# Find word and remove word and next set of brackets but leave everything between those brackets

Tags: unix, awk, sed, sh

I have a file which contains hundreds of similar snippets of the below, how could I use sed (or maybe awk) to change any occurrence of "from table(xxxx)" to "from xxxx"?

I'm trying to remove the "table" word and any brackets around whatever the actual table name is for "xxxx"?

There could also be a semi colon ";" on the end of the line too which needs to be kept.

**change this...**

```
...
     delete from r
     where (r.action_code, r.region_id) in ( SELECT action_code, region_id
                                               from table(paper_table)  --this line
                                           );
    insert into table_r(action_code, region_id, indicator_ind)
        SELECT t.action_code,
               t.region_id,
               t.indicator_ind
               from table(cheese_table) t;   --this line
...
```

**to this...**

```
...
         delete from r
         where (r.action_code, r.region_id) in ( SELECT action_code, region_id
                                                   from paper_table   --this line
                                               );
        insert into table_r(action_code, region_id, indicator_ind)
            SELECT t.action_code,
                   t.region_id,
                   t.indicator_ind
                   from cheese_table t;   --this line
....
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain why it did not work as you expected.

Answer (score 3):

I would use GNU `sed` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
 delete from r
 where (r.action_code, r.region_id) in ( SELECT action_code, region_id
                                           from table(paper_table)  --this line
                                       );
insert into table_r(action_code, region_id, indicator_ind)
    SELECT t.action_code,
           t.region_id,
           t.indicator_ind
           from table(cheese_table) t;   --this line
```

then

```
sed 's/from table(\([^)]*\))/from \1/g' file.txt
```

gives output

```
 delete from r
 where (r.action_code, r.region_id) in ( SELECT action_code, region_id
                                           from paper_table  --this line
                                       );
insert into table_r(action_code, region_id, indicator_ind)
    SELECT t.action_code,
           t.region_id,
           t.indicator_ind
           from cheese_table t;   --this line
```

Explanation: I use caputring group which is inside `(`...`)` following `from table`, from getting which I specify all characters but `)` and zero-or-more repetitions (`*`), note that `(` and `)` not prefixed with `\` denote literal `(` and `)` whilst prefixed with `\` are used to delimit capturing group.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)*

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick perfectly. Thanks for the explanation too!